# Start ROS node as root

Tags: ros, roslaunch, root, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have a Raspberry Pi with ROS running and I need to start two ROS nodes when the device starts. The problem is that one of the nodes must be started as root because one library needs this. I tried the start prefix in the roslaunch file but it didn’t worked. Is there any easy way to start the node as root?!
Best regards
Harald

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328994/start-ros-node-as-root/) by [Fresh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33841/fresh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check [q165246](https://answers.ros.org/question/165246/launch-node-with-root-permissions/)

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0